# How to convert IQueryable type to a list view model

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, model-view-controller

I'm working on an ASP.NET Core MVC project. In one of my controller class in its `Details` method, I have written code like this:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Details(int? id)
{
    IQueryable query = Enumerable.Empty<Applicant().AsQueryable();

    if (id == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    var applicant = await _context.Applicant
                                  .Include(a => a.ApplicantTypeNavigation)
                                  .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.ApplicantId == id);

    if (applicant.ApplicantType == 1)
    {
        query = from t1 in _context.Applicant // List<TABLE_1>
                join t2 in _context.PersonApplicant
                    on new { t1.ApplicantId, t1.ApplicantType } equals new { t2.ApplicantId, t2.ApplicantType }
                select new ApplicantViewModel { applicantvm = t1, personapplicantvm = t2 };
    }
    else if (applicant.ApplicantType == 2)
    {
        query = from t1 in _context.Applicant // List<TABLE_1>
                join t2 in _context.LegalApplicant
                    on new { t1.ApplicantId, t1.ApplicantType } equals new { t2.ApplicantId, t2.ApplicantType }
                select new ApplicantViewModel { applicantvm = t1, legalapplicantvm = t2 };
    }

    return View(query);
}
```

In my code, I should send the `IQueryable` query as a model to the `Details` view in order to show its contents. However, because query is of kind `IQueryable` and not of type a model, the view doesn't show anything.

Below is my markup and code in `Details` view:

```
@model CSDDashboard.Models.ApplicantViewModel

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Details";
}

<h1>Details</h1>

<div>
<h4>Applicant </h4>
<hr />
<dl class="row">
    <dt class="col-sm-2">
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.applicantvm.ApplicantType)
    </dt>
    <dt class="col-sm-2">
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.applicantvm.Name)
    </dt>
    <dt class="col-sm-2">
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.applicantvm.Address)
    </dt>
    <dt class="col-sm-2">
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.applicantvm.Description)
    </dt>
    <dt class="col-sm-2">
    </dt>
    <dt class="col-sm-2">
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.legalapplicantvm.NationalCode)
    </dt>
    <dt class="col-sm-2">
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.legalapplicantvm.RegisterNo)
    </dt>
    <dt class="col-sm-2">
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.legalapplicantvm.EconomicCode)
    </dt>
    <dt class="col-sm-2">
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.personapplicantvm.NationalCode)
    </dt>
    <dt class="col-sm-2">
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.personapplicantvm.Username)
    </dt>
    <dt class="col-sm-2">
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.personapplicantvm.IssuePlace)
    </dt>
    <dt class="col-sm-2">
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.personapplicantvm.BirthCertificateNo)
    </dt>
</dl>
</div>
<div>
   <a asp-action="Edit" asp-route- id="@Model.applicantvm.ApplicantId">Edit</a> |
```

Back to list

```
    namespace CSDDashboard.Models
   {
    public class ApplicantViewModel
    {
    public Applicant applicantvm { get; set; }
    public PersonApplicant personapplicantvm { get; set; }
    public LegalApplicant legalapplicantvm { get; set; }
     }
   }
```

I think the problem is I send an `IQueryable` type to the view instead of model type. But I don't know how to convert it.

I appreciate it if anyone suggests me any solution.

Comment: Could you please give us your `ApplicantViewModel`?

Comment: **IQueryable** - not "IQuaryable" ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In View** is expecting an `ApplicantViewModel` model, So in Controller, you should get one item by using `FirstOrDefault()`.

Besides, You should limit item like `where t1.ApplicantType == 1 && t1.ApplicantId == id`.

```
if (applicant.ApplicantType == 1)
 query = from t1 in _context.Applicant // List<TABLE_1>
        join t2 in _context.PersonApplicant
         on new { t1.ApplicantId, t1.ApplicantType } equals new { t2.ApplicantId, t2.ApplicantType }
        where t1.ApplicantType == 1 && t1.ApplicantId == id
        select new ApplicantViewModel { applicantvm = t1, personapplicantvm = t2 };


else if (applicant.ApplicantType == 2)
 query = (from t1 in _context.Applicant // List<TABLE_1>
         join t2 in _context.LegalApplicant
            on new { t1.ApplicantId, t1.ApplicantType } equals new { t2.ApplicantId, t2.ApplicantType }
         where t1.ApplicantType == 2 && t1.ApplicantId == id
         select new ApplicantViewModel { applicantvm = t1, legalapplicantvm = t2 }).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I added where clause to the mentioned line of my code. However, the "query" is of type IQueryable. And IQuaryable doesn't have the method to return SingleOrDefault. How can I do that?

Comment: You should add `using System.Linq` namespace as well.

Comment: There is an error when adding .FirstOrDefault() after the select like yours. The error is "Can not implicitly convert type ApplicantViewModel to System.Linq.IQuaryable. An explicit conversion exists(Are you missing a cast?)"

Comment: You should remove this line `IQueryable query = Enumerable.Empty<Applicant().AsQueryable();` or assign it like `var query = new ApplicantViewModel()` to reuse the variable below